# Amazon S3 Request Overload

Tags: c#, asynchronous, amazon-s3, timeout, restsharp

I have a WebApi Route that makes asynchronous requests of Amazon S3. The number of requests is in the thousands. It looks something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < pdfs.Count; i++)
{
    //stuff ...

    var getPdfClient = new RestClient(pdf.Url);
    var getPdfRequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    getPdfRequest.AddParameter("pdfIndex", i);

    getPdfClient.ExecuteAsync(getPdfRequest, getPdfResponse => // Download the PDF async
    {
          //do stuff on response
    }
}
```

As written this results in a Timeout response after so many requests.

The problem does not go away by increasing the request timeout `request.Timeout = 14400000;`

The problem does go away by putting a `Thread.Sleep(100)` before the execute async. This leads me to believe the timeout is the result of bombarding S3 with so many requests.

Obviously Thread.Sleep is not the right answer. What should I change to correctly interface with S3 under this load?

Comment: Did you check DefaultConnectinLimit in your machine? Just add this code var noofconnections = ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit;

Comment: ok then connection limit is not problem

Comment: you may send requests in batches

Comment: What would be a good way to do that? make an arbitrary for loop?